# Using BufferedReader to two dimensional array including a counter

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

Having an in issue with some code I am doing for school. Trying to keep it within my logic (and inherently failing). Just wondering if there are any tips on making this work;

```
public static String[][] sortWords(BufferedReader in, int n) throws IOException{
    String line = "";
    int ctr = 0;
    String[][] words = new String[n][2];

    for(int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        words[m][1] = "1"; 
    }

    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        String a[]=line.split(" ");    
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
            for(int h = ctr; h < n; h++) {
                if (words[h][0].equals(a[i])) {
                    words[h][1] = "" + (Integer.parseInt(words[h][1])+1);
                } else{
                    words[ctr][0] = a[i];
                    ctr++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        line=in.readLine();
    }
    return words;
}
```

What I am trying to do is take a txt file that is quite large (70k words) and dissect this. This method I was thinking could do the following;
- find all the words in file
- find how many occurrences of each word
- store both values in a 2D array to make it easy to access.

If I am off base I understand.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you will be skipping a line with this code `}}} line=in.readLine();`

Comment: As you set the count to start from 1, when you found the first occurrence of the word you update the counter and end with 1 occurrence and count == 2. You should start from 0 or move the initialization part in the loop. And more, you set the length of the array to the number of lines, but the word you can find are possible much more than that.

Comment: It's easier to store the words and their occurrences in a `HashMap<String, Integer>`. Each time you find a new word, you place it in the `HashMap` and put it's value to `1`, and if it is already in the hash, you update the value using `++` or whatever you want.

Comment: And you should get rid of the last `line=in.readLine();`

Comment: Thanks all, I I got it sorted using the HashMaps method. With regards to what Mario said regarding the array length I already ran a method that counted the words, so I had the total number of words, so I set the array to that even though it would be shorter (due to uiniques). This also was the problem too, once I had the BufferedReader going through a method it was closing and doing nothing, maybe if i fixed the readLIne part it might of worked(doubtful I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments are on point, but I will try to translate them into code. At each step I've commented out every non-modified line so the changes are clearer.

First off, screw that two-dimensional array. It's restrictive and cumbersome to work with. Let's use a Map instead:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> sortWords(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{
//    String line = "";
    Map<String, Integer> wordsCount = new HashMap<>();
//
//    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
//        String a[]=line.split(" ");
//        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
//            a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
            Integer count = wordsCount.get(a[i]); // Get current count for this word
            if (count == null) count = 0; // Initialize on first appearance
            count++; // Update counter
            wordsCount.put(a[i], count); // Save the updated value
//        }
//        line=in.readLine();
//    }
//    return words;
//}
```

No need to initialize the array, no additional loops, no `String` to `int` conversion... Just get the value associated to that word and update it. And now we don't need to know the number of words beforehand, so the second `int n` parameter can be safely removed!

Now, I see that you're using a very basic, C-like, before-year-2000 idiom (with all those `for(;;)` and arrays and such). It's perfectly valid, but you're missing out on more modern and more useful constructs. So how about we use the **[enhanced for loop](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/480-the-enhanced-for-loop.html)** available since 2004?

```
//public static Map<String, Integer> sortWords(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{
//    String line = "";
//    Map<String, Integer> wordsCount = new HashMap<>();
//
//    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
//        String a[]=line.split(" ");
        for(String word : a) {
            word = word.toUpperCase();
            Integer count = wordsCount.get(word); // Get current count for this word
//            if (count == null) count = 0; // Initialize on first appearance
//            count++; // Update counter
            wordsCount.put(word, count); // Save the updated value
//        }
//        line=in.readLine();
//    }
//    return wordsCount;
//}
```

Clearer syntax, we know exactly what type of object we're dealing with in the loop... and best of all, it lets you **inline** some of your code to make it cleaner. Like this:

```
//public static Map<String, Integer> sortWords(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{
//    String line = "";
//    Map<String, Integer> wordsCount = new HashMap<>();
//
//    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        for(String word : line.toUpperCase().split(" ")) {
//            Integer count = wordsCount.get(word); // Get current count for this word
//            if (count == null) count = 0; // Initialize on first appearance
//            count++; // Update counter
//            wordsCount.put(word, count); // Save the updated value
//        }
//        line=in.readLine();
//    }
//    return wordsCount;
//}
```

Now the `toUpperCase()` method will be called just once per line instead of once per word, and we got rid of that `String a[]` which was hurting everybody's eyes ;-P

The last thing left to do is removing that extra `readLine()` at the end. Do that, and now your code should look like this:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> sortWords(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    Map<String, Integer> wordsCount = new HashMap<>();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        for(String word : line.toUpperCase().split(" ")) {
            Integer count = wordsCount.get(word); // Get current count for this word
            if (count == null) count = 0; // Initialize on first appearance
            count++; // Update counter
            wordsCount.put(word, count); // Save the updated value
        }
    }
    return wordsCount;
}
```

Much nicer!
You can use the method like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myWords.txt"));
Map words = sortWords(in);
int numberOfHellos = words.get("Hello");
int numberOfGreetings = numberOfHellos + words.get("Hi") + words.get("Howdy");
```

Comment: thank you again. This was the full problem outline and what I ended up with - https://github.com/AussieDropBear/H274
I didn't want to post everything because I wanted to understand not get the answer, so again I appreciate your help :)